# Networking - SNMP Request/Response Mode - How order is done? No timestamp field

Tags: request, timestamp, response, snmp, wireshark

I have a minor question related to the SNMP protocol.
I know that on trap mode, the agent can report to the manager the messages, and this ones can be order using the timestamp field of the SNMP.

But on request/response mode, when the queries are made from the manager to the agent, there is no timestamp field on the request message neither on response message, so how can the manager order this messages?
Imagine a world where many requests are done and many responses are done... ? Does the messages are ordered on the application like wireshark related to the time of the actual capture on wireshark..? or..?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the messages are ordered on the application like wireshark related to the time of the actual capture on wireshark

Yes.

The only "ordering" that the manager can do is to sort by the arrival time of the responses.

> Imagine a world where many requests are done and many responses are done

The manager would match requests and replies by response ID.